# How do I use django settings in my logging.ini file?

Tags: python, django, logging

I have a BASE_DIR setting in my settings.py file:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

I need to use this variable in my logging.ini file to setup my file handler paths.

The initialization of logging happens in the same file, the settings.py file, below my BASE_DIR variable. Here I tell it the path of my logging.ini file:

```
LOG_INIT_DONE=False
if not LOG_INIT_DONE:
   logging.config.fileConfig(LOGGING_INI)
   LOG_INIT_DONE=True
```

I noticed fileConfig can take a default parameter. I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to use this parameter.

Thanks,
Pete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html?highlight=logging#logging.fileConfig),

```
logging.fileConfig(fname[, defaults])
```

> Reads the logging configuration from a
>   ConfigParser-format file named fname.
>   This function can be called several
>   times from an application, allowing an
>   end user the ability to select from
>   various pre-canned configurations (if
>   the developer provides a mechanism to
>   present the choices and load the
>   chosen configuration). Defaults to be
>   passed to ConfigParser can be
>   specified in the defaults argument.

So you can simply pass as the second argument a dictionary like

```
{'basedir': BASE_DIR}
```

and then just interpolate its `basedir` entry in your `logging.ini` file:

```
[SomeSection]
somefile: %(basedir)s/foobar.txt
```

and the like!

Comment: Thanks Alex. I actually had it working by the time you responded; however, in all fairness, no where does it say that parameter expects a dictionary. Additionally, it doesn't mention that is parses the config file replacing keys in defaults dict.

Comment: @slypete, the `logging.fileConfig` docs, as above quoted, mention `ConfigParser`, and the `ConfigParser` docs are the ones that say that `defaults` is a dict and is used in interpolation (so if you're not 100% familiar with `ConfigParser`, when the `logging` docs mention it you'll clearly go look at the `ConfigParser` docs and find out the details -- wouldn't make sense for the `logging` docs to repeat all those details, though a hyperlink to `ConfigParser` _would_ make sense... normally the online docs do hyperlink, but, I believe, not in this specific case;-).